# XPath to scrape data in a <DL>

Tags: xpath

In a webpage I like to scrape data from, there are several "**Data Fields**" in a **DL** with titles **DT** and the values **DD**. Sometimes there are two **DD** in a **DT**

I copied the HTML code:

```
<dl id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_ContentPlaceHolder1_wideProfile_listingDetails_dlDetailedInformation" class="listingProfile_details">
            <dt><strong>Location:</strong></dt>
            <dd>Pasco County, FL</dd>
            <dt><strong>Employees:</strong></dt>
            <dd>11</dd>
            <dt><strong>Furniture, Fixtures, &amp; Equipment (FF&amp;E):</strong></dt>
            <dd>Included in asking price</dd>
            <dt><strong>Reason for Selling:</strong></dt>
            <dd>semi-retirement</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to scrape all values within the `<DL>...</DL>`

I tried using this XPath

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_ContentPlaceHolder1_wideProfile_listingDetails_dlDetailedInformation"][contains(child::text(), "title-text 1")]/following-sibling::*
```

But it didn't work - could someone please help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I did find a XPath that worked for one **DT** and its **DD**

//dl[@id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_ContentPlaceHolder1_wideProfile_listingDetails_dlDetailedInformation"]/dt[. = "Location:"]/following-sibling::dd